# Why use "slim = tf.contrib.slim" instead of import slim normally?

Tags: tensorflow, python-import, tf-slim

In most tensorflow slim tutorials, slim module is loaded using,

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

it does not seem making any difference (am I missing anything?), if I do

```
from tensorflow.contrib import slim
```

Is there any particular reason that we want to use 'slim = tf.contrib.slim' instead of 'import'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a difference between the

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

and

```
from tensorflow.contrib import slim
```

I believe that the former is used to avoid writing the entire `tensorflow` name.

Comment: Thanks. I thought, maybe, using 'slim = tf.contrib.slim', slim is always imported after other libraries import, there might be some dependencies?